# How to create a new column in a pandas data frame for values with the same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have one initial table which has two columns, one called Numbers and the other called Tags. I wanted to create a new table which puts all the Tags with the same number on the same row.

This is the table that I initially have:

| Numbers | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | catarina |
| 2 | pedro |
| 3 | joao |
| 4 | banana |
| 5 | massa |
| 6 | laranjas |

And this is the table that I want to end up with:

| Numbers | Name1 | Name2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | catarina | banana |
| 2 | pedro | massa |
| 3 | joao | laranjas |

The code that I had before was this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Numbers': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'Tag': ['catarina', 'pedro', 'joao', 'banana', 'massa', 'laranjas']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.pivot(index='Numbers', columns=df.groupby('Numbers').cumcount()+1, values='Tag')
df.columns.name = None
df = df.rename(columns={1: 'Name1', 2: 'Name2'})
```

and this is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\santos.c.28\viscometer\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3802, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\santos.c.28\viscometer\viscometer\data_restructuring.py", line 6, in <module>
    df = df.pivot(index='Numbers', columns=df.groupby('Numbers').cumcount()+1, values='Tag')
  File "C:\Users\santos.c.28\viscometer\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\santos.c.28\viscometer\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 8567, in pivot     
    return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
  File "C:\Users\santos.c.28\viscometer\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\santos.c.28\viscometer\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 525, in pivot
    data_columns = [data[col] for col in columns_listlike]
  File "C:\Users\santos.c.28\viscometer\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 525, in <listcomp>
    data_columns = [data[col] for col in columns_listlike]
  File "C:\Users\santos.c.28\viscometer\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3807, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\santos.c.28\viscometer\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3804, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 1
```

What is the reason for this problem and how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code is missing the parameter columns= when the pivot function was being used. Try df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Numbers', 'Tag'])

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

I've change `df.pivot()` for `pd.pivot_table()` and I've improved the way you rename the columns after you process the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Numbers': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'Tag': ['catarina', 'pedro', 'joao', 'banana', 'massa', 'laranjas']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Numbers', columns=df.groupby('Numbers').cumcount()+1, values='Tag', aggfunc='first')

df.columns = [f"Name{i}" for i in range(1,len(df.columns)+1)]

df
```

Output:

| Numbers | Name1 | Name2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | catarina | banana |
| 2 | pedro | massa |
| 3 | joao | laranjas |